# Joomla is not reading images in my PHP code

Tags: php, joomla, dreamweaver

I don't know why Dreamweaver can preview the images inside my PHP but when I run it on my Joomla website they won't appear.

This is my code:

```
<div id="wb_Image2" style="position:absolute;left:26px;top:805px;width:1393px;height:779px;z-index:1;">
<img src="images/unjc7g4477.jpg" id="Image2" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could be difficult to help me.

But the problem was that i was making confusion with folders, joomla was looking for php files in another directory where the files wasn't there.

Thanks for anything